# Installing package (gahgu95av2.db) in R

Tags: r

I have a problem with installing package (`gahgu95av2.db`) in R. How can I deal with this? Please see below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `gahgu95av2.db` has been dropped from Bioconductor versions >3.3. However you can still install the package from source.

1. [Download the source file](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.4/data/annotation/src/contrib/gahgu95av2.db_2.0.1.tar.gz)
2. Go to the folder with `gahgu95av2.db_2.0.1.tar.gz`; then open an R terminal and do

   ```
   install.packages(
       "gahgu95av2.db_2.0.1.tar.gz", 
       repos = NULL, 
       type = "source");
   ```